# Iphone Database saving image

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I am saving a name(TextField) and image(UIImage - from a photo library) when i click the button(LoadImage -- on view) the photo library of iphone opens up and then i select one photo from it, then i enter a name in textfield and then click save(Button) on the view to save the name as well as the image related to the name gets saved into the database, but i am not able to do that i have never saved a image in database(BLOB) can any one tell me the exact code needed to perform this, so that on the next view when i type the name it should load the same image related to that name on the second view, plz can any one do this for me .. coding will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to learn how to use database management in iOS? I suggest you [follow this course by Stanford University](https://itunes.apple.com/fr/itunes-u/ipad-iphone-application-development/id480479762) on iTunes U. It's very well explained and shows you concrete examples and demos of how to do things. The lectures you want to watch are 13. Core Data and 14. Core Data demo.